# Qt text editor project: auto-indenting when Enter is pressed after an opening curly brace

Tags: qt, qt5, text-editor, auto-indent

I'm working on a text editor project in Qt, and I've added the following method override to a class that's of type `QPlainTextEdit`:

```
/* Custom handler for events. Used to handle the case of Enter being pressed after an opening brace.
 */
bool Editor::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    bool isKeyPress = event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress;

    if(isKeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *key = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);

        if(key->key() == Qt::Key_Enter || key->key() == Qt::Key_Return)
        {
            QString documentContents = document()->toPlainText();

            if(documentContents.length() >= 1)
            {
                int indexToLeftOfCursor = textCursor().position() - 1;

                if(indexToLeftOfCursor >= 0 && indexToLeftOfCursor < documentContents.length())
                {
                    bool hitEnterAfterOpeningBrace = documentContents.at(indexToLeftOfCursor) == '{';

                    if(hitEnterAfterOpeningBrace)
                    {
                        // TODO determine indentation level of the opening brace
                        insertPlainText("\n\t\n}");
                        QTextCursor cursor = textCursor();
                        cursor.setPosition(cursor.position() - 3);
                        setTextCursor(cursor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Without the code for setting the text cursor's position, the result looks like this:

[image]

The cursor ends up on line 4, and there's a tab on line 2. My intent is to move the cursor so it sits to the right of the tab, so I tried to do that with the code I've written. But that gives me this:

[image]

Here, the indent is still on line 2, but now there's an extra line between the tab and the closing brace, which is a little odd.

Even more strange is that this happens regardless of what new position I enter. I tried doing `cursor.position() - 2` and `cursor.position() - 1` out of curiosity, for example, but I still got the same result.

What am I misunderstanding here about inserting the text and moving the cursor?

Comment: I think part of the problem is that you should return true after handling the enter to prevent the default behaviour of the enter key being triggered.

Comment: @Eelke That did the trick! Thank you :)